# Is there any online lecture series that covers "Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach"?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

I am trying to cover the Computational Complexity :A Modern approach by Boaz Borak and Sanjeev Arora. Are there any nice lecture series that cover this material ?

Answer (score 9):

These courses by Prof. Ryan O'Donnell are excellent:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRnnEOAQZF8&list=PLm3J0oaFux3b8Gg1DdaJOzYNsaXYLAOKH

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxhpiYKFQd8&list=PLm3J0oaFux3YL5vLXpzOyJiLtqLp6dCW2

They cover most relevant material.